# Changing the Location of an Image added in Javascript with a CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css

I'm still pretty new to HTML and the languages commonly associated with it. Right now, I'm trying to adjust the location of an image I added in through a function defined in Javascript like I usually would in CSS with something like `margin-left: 100px`.

EDIT: Added code and clarification

```
case 1:
        demo.innerHTML = "You win cookies!";
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'cookies.jpg';
        img.onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://link.com/';}
```

document.body.appendChild(img);

Comment: css is for style, if you want to change the href of an element, use javascript. post your code to get a better help.

Comment: can you explain further on what you really want? seems like your objective is a bit not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties to position elements via Javascript, e.g.:

`var elem = document.getElementById("elementid");
elem.style.left=200;
elem.style.top=200;`

you may need to set:

`elem.style.position='absolute';`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://data.whicdn.com/images/27433830/large.jpg';
img.id = "myImage"; // <-- give it an ID
img.onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://link.com/';
}

document.body.appendChild(img);

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
  image.src = "http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/house/house-07.jpg";
}
```

```html
<button id="button">switch</button>
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me what this would look like within my current code? I'm struggling to get this to work for me.

Comment: I have changed the code. The "switch-button" is at the bottom.